# opengl not filling in polygon

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to draw a filled in circle, but when I draw this, it only shows in wireframe, here is the code I'm using to draw:

```
void render_circle(Vec2 position, float radius, Vec4 colour) {
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glColor4f(colour.x, colour.y, colour.z, colour.w);

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    int num_segments = 30; //@todo: make this scale for larger radius
    for(int i = 0; i < num_segments; i++) {
        float theta = 2.0f * math_pi * (float)i / (float)num_segments;
        float x = radius * cosf(theta);
        float y = radius * sinf(theta);
        glVertex2f(position.x + x, position.y + y);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: Please, try `GL_POLYGON` instead of `GL_LINE_LOOP`. You cannot expect something filled from OpenGL when you explicitly asked for lines. ;-) [glBegin()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GL_LINE_LOOP` is a [line primitive type](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives). If you want to draw a filled polygon, then you have to use a [polygon primitive type](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives). For instance `GL_TRINAGLE_FAN`.
It is only possible to correctly draw [convex geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_geometry). [Concave polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_polygon) may not be represented correctly, by a primitive. A possibility to deal with this, is to split concave polygons into convex parts.